# Assign value to a list using slice notation with assignee

Tags: python, list, slice

I have seen people using `[:]` to make a swallow copy of a list, like:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a[0] = 5
>>> print a
[5, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I understand that. However, I have seen pleople using this notation when assigning to lists as well, like:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [4,5,6,7]
>>> a[:] = b
>>> print a
[4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> print b
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

But I don't really understand why they use `[:]` here. Is there a difference I don't know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is indeed a difference between `a[:] = b` and `a = b`.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [4,5,6,7]
>>> c = [8,9,0,1]
>>> c = b
>>> a[:] = b
>>> b[0] = 0
>>> a
[4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> c
[0, 5, 6, 7]
>>>
```

When you write `a = b`, a is a reference to same list as b: any change in b will affect a

when you write `a[:] = b` a is a list initialized with the elements of b: a change in b will not affect a

---

And there also a difference between `a[:] = b` and `a = b[:]`.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [4,5,6,7]
>>> c = a
>>> a = b[:]
>>> a
[4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [4,5,6,7]
>>> c = a
>>> a[:] = b
>>> a
[4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> c
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

With `a = b[:]`, you create a new list with the elements from b, if another variable pointed to a it is not affected

With `a[:] = b`, you change the elements of a. If another variable pointed to a it is also changed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes , when you use `[:]` in the left side , it changes (mutates) the list in place , instead of assigning a new list to the name (variable). To see that , try the following code -

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
a[:] = [5,4,3,2]
print(a)
print(b)
```

You would see both 'a' and 'b' changed .

To see the difference between above and normal assignment , try the below code out -

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
a = [5,4,3,2]
print(a)
print(b)
```

You will see that only 'a' has changed , 'b' still point to `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: I think you mean I wouldn't see both changed? Since `a[:]` is a swallow copy of itself that doesn't point to `b` anymore?

Comment: When used on the left side of assignment operator they are not creating copies. They are for mutating the list in place .

Answer (score 2):

It's more about how it copies the list than anything. Example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> a = b
>>> b[0] = 9
>>> a
[9, 5, 6, 7]
>>> b
[9, 5, 6, 7]
```

Here, `a` now references `b`, so changing a value of `b` will also affect `a`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> a[:] = b
>>> b[0] = 9
>>> a
[4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> b
[9, 5, 6, 7]
```

In the case of using slicing, it is only a shallow copy of the elements of the list, so a change in `b` won't affect `a`. Hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: It is a shallow copy in your second example, the first creates a reference

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the correction